# Migrating to SQL Server in TeamCity: A driver for the source database not found

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, teamcity

I'm trying to move my TeamCity instance to SQL Server.  I followed the instructions in the docs for [Setting up an External Database](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Setting%20up%20an%20External%20Database#SettingupanExternalDatabase-MicrosoftSQLServer).

Now I'm going through [Migrating to an External Database](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Migrating+to+an+External+Database#MigratingtoanExternalDatabase-dbswitch) and running the maintainDb command:

`.\maintainDB.cmd migrate -A c:\users\jkodroff\.buildserver -T C:\Users\jkodroff\.BuildServer\config\database.properties`

And I get this output:

```
Java executable is found: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin\java.exe'.
Using logs directory C:\TeamCity\logs
TeamCity maintenance tool. Copyright 2013 JetBrains s.r.o. All Rights Reserved.

Command line arguments: migrate -A c:\users\jkodroff\.buildserver -T C:\Users\jkodroff\.BuildServer\config\database.properties
Using TeamCity data directory: C:\Users\jkodroff\.BuildServer
Using database settings from the TeamCity data directory for source database: C:\Users\jkodroff\.BuildServer\config\database.properties
Using source database
        database type: MSSQL
        connection string: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/teamcity
Cannot proceed with 'migrate' command: A driver for the source database not found. Please ensure you have driver jars in C:\Users\jkodroff\.BuildServer\lib\jdbc.
Critical error has occurred during command execution.
```

I've verified that both `sqljdbc.jar` and `sqljdbc4.jar` are in the directory indicated, so what gives?

Answer (score 8):

The fact that you have `sqljdbc.jar` and `sqljdbc4.jar` indicates that you are using the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver, but the connection string is for the jTDS driver. Make sure you use the [correct connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx) for the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC or that you use the [jTDS JDBC driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Second: you should use either `sqljdbc.jar` (which is for Java 5) or `sqljdbc4.jar` (which is for Java 6 and later), not both; loading both might lead to unexpected behavior due to classloading order etc!